# Error [TOKEN_INVALID], Turns valid token into invalid token

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**My Code**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
require("dotenv").config()

const Token = "*MY VALID TOKEN*"
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_MEMBERS"
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "hi!"){
        message.reply("Hello")
    }
})

const welcomeChannelID = "935422032458444901"

client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) =>{
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelID).send(`<@${member.id}> Welcome to the Server!`)
})

client.login(process.env.Token)
```

**The Error**

```
D:\DBS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:129
    const invalidToken = new Error(WSCodes[4004]);
                         ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (D:\DBS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:129:26)
    at Client.login (D:\DBS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:254:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DBS\index.js:29:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}

Node.js v17.3.0
```

I have Checked and Double checked my token, and it IS valid, There is something wrong in my code, can you please help me figure it out? thanks!
.......................................................

Comment: If you define `const Token = "*MY VALID TOKEN*"` why do you use `client.login(process.env.Token)` and not just `client.login(Token)`? Have you checked the value of `process.env.Token`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `client.login(process.env.Token)`, then you should have a .env file where you put your token inside. If you're putting your token at

```js
const Token = "*MY VALID TOKEN*"
```

Then simply just do `client.login(Token);`

Answer (score 0):

Your token should be in `.env` file following format:

```
Token=YourTokenIsHere
```

For example:

```
Token=cjKFmWWHeabkY5cjKFmWWHeabkY5cjKFmWW
```

*Not real token in example*

Make sure you have the correct token from the Developer Portal
[image]